# how to get the session in thymeleaf without spring security

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm doing my login for an application without spring security so I use the normal login with session, but not sure I'm on a good way. 
This is my controller

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public String login(Model model,@RequestParam(name = "email")String email, 
@RequestParam(name = "password") String password , HttpServletRequest request){

    int user=0;
    int pass=0;
    Utilisateur utilisateur=utilisateurMetier.findByEmail(email);
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();




    if(utilisateurMetier.checkEmailLogin(email)==false){


       if( utilisateurMetier.comparePassword(password,utilisateur)==true){

           session.setAttribute("mySession", utilisateur);

           System.out.println("'tres bien");
           return "utilisateur/home";
       }else {
           pass=1;
           model.addAttribute("pass",pass);
           System.out.println("pas bin");
           return "redirect:/utilisateur/loginForm";
       }


    }else {
            user=1;
            model.addAttribute("user", user);
        System.out.println("existe pas");
        return "redirect:/utilisateur/login";
    }

}
```

If the password and the email exists I send the session to the view "utilisateur/home";

This is my template Thymeleaf view:

```
<div>
<h1>Login</h1>
</div>

 <h1 th:text="'la session est '+${session.mySession}"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I get my session but I'm not sure it is like this because I know the session is a global variable and if I want to get it in another view I don't suppose is possible

thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with context attribute.

```
<h4 style="color: white;" th:text="${#ctx.httpSession.id}">SessionID </h4>
```